# How to use excel filter function to filter all items that match my list of names

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a long list of company names, I'd like to try and use the `Filter` function in Excel365 to be able to filter for only the names that appear in my list.

```
=FILTER(MasterSheet!$C:$D,MATCH(Sheet1!$H$5:$H$7,MasterSheet!$C:$C,0))
```

I've tried the above here. `MasterSheet` contains all the names and my range H5-H7 contains a list of names that i'd like to filter by

Comment: Not sure on the use of the match function in your filter function. I believe this would work: =FILTER(MasterSheet!$C:$D, MasterSheet!$C:$C=Sheet1!$H$5:$H$7)

Comment: hmm - tried that and still getting #N/A @gns100

Comment: when I break out just that formula and make it the following, i;m getting values for the first 3 rows and the rest are #N?A =MasterSheet!$C$4:$C$5000=Sheet1!$H$8:$H$10

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I reread up on the filter function: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759 and if you want an OR condition you need to list it out as three separate conditions so: `=FILTER(MasterSheet!$C:$D, (MasterSheet!$C:$C=Sheet1!$H$5)+(MasterSheet!$C:$C=Sheet1!$H$6)+(MasterSheet!$C:$C=Sheet1!$H$7))`

Comment: Oh wow, what if I have a list of 15-20 names? I was just keeping it brief for the example but in practice, mastersheet could contain thousands of names and I'd be trying to filter anywhere between 15-30 at a time).

Comment: For a long list, use PowerQuery and Merge with Inner join

Comment: I'm not familiar with that. My gut is telling me there has to be a simpler way. Basically, take a long list of names and return true or false if one of the names appears in a smaller subset or names

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have your main data in this range:

```
$A$2:$M$2000
```

In column A are the company names.

And you have your list of 30 companies you want to filter by in Sheet2, say, in $A$2:$A$30.

So, you add a new column to the data in the main sheet, in column N, with a formula like this:

```
=XLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$30,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$30,"")<>""
```

This XLOOKUP will take the company name in column A of your main sheet, and look for it in the list of 30 companies. If it finds it, it will return the company name, otherwise it will return an empty string (blank). We are then testing if the return value is not blank. If it's not blank, then it found the name in the list of 30, and the formula returns TRUE. You can now filter the main sheet on column N=TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the MATCH in ISNUMBER and the first criteria must have the same number of rows as the filter area:

```
=FILTER(MasterSheet!$C:$D,ISNUMBER(MATCH(MasterSheet!$C:$C,Sheet1!$H$5:$H$7,0)))
```

---

One note, though this will work, it is considered better practice to limit the number of rows to the largest the dataset will become ie:

```
=FILTER(MasterSheet!$C$1:$D$10000,ISNUMBER(MATCH(MasterSheet!$C$1:$C$10000,Sheet1!$H$5:$H$7,0)))
```

Remember that these are array type formula and the larger the ranges the more calculations that must be performed.